# Basic questions regarding the use of Webmatrix and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, webmatrix

I have been experimenting and researching the use of Webmatrix with AJAX for the last few days and unfortunately I can't seem to find enough information to help me get my project to work. I'm hoping to learn more about how it all works in principle in order to progress. Hopefully this will also be helpful to others who are learning about this. I would appreciate any bits of advice and helpful links.

(Excuse the length of this post.)

**A little background on my project:**

I'm using a cs class to assemble several `List<int>`'s and `List<double>`'s, using data out of a database and some semi-complex algorithms. These lists contain information on a number of videos, and I'm using these lists to help me build a little video application that eventually plays a generated list of videos with html5 video and canvas. 
I have been testing this project in a few different programming environments and frameworks (using only javaScript, using openFrameworks and C++, using php with a database and ajax, javaScript, etc). I have not had any trouble using ajax before, but I'm getting stuck trying to realise the concept in Webmatrix.

**What is the relationship between C# datatypes, JSON and javaScript?**

A solution I used with php was something like this:

```
$sequenceData = array("array1" => $dataArray1, 
    "array2" => $dataArray2, 
    "array3" => $dataArray3,
    "array4" => $dataArray4);

echo json_encode($sequenceData);
```

and then used AJAX to use these arrays in javaScript. I don't know if it's a good solution, but it was simple enough for me and it worked.

Now I have been trying to find a good solution to do this using C# datatypes. (I only really learned C# in the last few weeks, so please bear with me.) My current thought is that my data would either be, for example, a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, converting my data to strings, so they're all the same, but that seems a little clumsy and this is where I wonder how JSON treats these datatypes and also if (how) javaScript would recognize them? 
Alternatively, it might be more elegant to use a simple class (struct?) so I could pass the data as one object. I would still use Lists in this case, so the question remains, would this work? Would javaScript a C# object? Are Lists treated as arrays? I used Google and Lynda.com to get more information on c#, json, etc but I have not really been able to fully understand how these things work.

**JSON encoding in Webmatrix**

I have been using mainly two sources to understand the JSON helper and getting encoded data via AJAX:

from [microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-aspnet-razor-syntax-with-html5-and-jquery) and
from [mikesdotnetting.com](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/160/WebMatrix-Working-With-The-JSON-Helper) (links to specific articles)

Unfortunately I have not been able to successfully pass data from my cshtml files yet. I was looking to get more information on the JSON helper, but again haven't found much useful information online. Using jQuery's `$.ajax` (which I used in my previous trial, along with php) as well as the `$.getJSON` (which is used in the above links) functions, I could not successfully retrieve the JSON data from the cshtml file. I figured that the code, continuing from javaScript with AJAX, wouldn't be essentially different than when I previously used php to create the data to pass on, so I wonder if I'm going wrong in encoding the JSON data.

I mainly tried these two concepts as seen on mikesdotnetting.com

```
var json = Json.Encode(data);
Response.Write(json);

Json.Write(data, Response.Output);
```

All I did with php was `echo json_encode($sequenceData);` and everything seemed to work by itself, so I wonder if I'm going wrong here, and how php and webmatrix/razor/c# work differently here.

I hope this post isn't too vague. I tried a lot of different code bits and methods to approach this, which is why I haven't attached more of the code I'm using. I figure that I need to adapt my entire process and concept more to how it would be most suitable to do in Webmatrix, C# etc, rather than to just "translate". I would really like to understand more about these topics (the JSON helper, the communication with AJAX, data types in the process, etc) and hope people can share some advice.

(Thanks if you're still with me at the end of this post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, there are a number of predefined primitive data types: int, string, double, byte, datetime etc. You can use a class to define your own more complex data type. An example Video data type declaration might look like this:

```
public class Video
{
    public int VideoId {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public DateTime ReleaseDate {get;set;}
}
```

You can instantiate an instance of the Video class using the following syntax:

```
Video myVideo = new Video{
    VideoId = 1,
    Title = "Spartacus",
    ReleaseDate = new DateTime(1960, 12, 8)
};
```

So far, so good. You can instantiate many videos and keep them all together from a programming point of view in some sort of collection. You have a number of choices for the type of collection you use, but a generic `List<T>` is common. `T` stands for the type that the list holds; in this case `T` is `Video`:

```
List<Video> videoCollection = new List<Video>();
videoCollection.Add(myVideo);
```

Because the type that the list holds is declared, the list is said to be strongly-typed. Arrays are not strongly typed. They can contain any kind of object.

In WebMatrix (or more accurately, the ASP.NET Web Pages Framework) the Json helper has methods that take your object or collection, and serialize them to JSON. Each JSON representation of a video will have VideoId, Title and ReleaseDate properties:

```
[{"VideoId":1,"Title":"Spartacus","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(-286070400000)\/"}]
```

From that point, you can work with JSON objects using jQuery in the page file in exactly the same way as you do in PHP.

In the article you referenced on my site, the data is obtained from the database, and there is  some unseen magic behind the scenes. The data is transformed into a `dynamic` type, with properties added at runtime by the framework based on the columns of data obtained by the database.

Comment: Another great answer by MikeDotNetting

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and simple answer, Mike. Your posts on here and your blog articles have been incredibly helpful in my learning efforts. 

Making the transition to Webmatrix/c# has been a bit difficult. I am familiar with writing classes and other concepts of OOP, but I always find it tricky to figure out the details.

But there are a number of things in this post that help me a lot (my new demo is working after I also did some more work last week) and give me more food for research.

Comment: Yup, this is just another example of why I appreciate Mike's answers so much. A lot of times I'll stop and read his answers to questions I already know, just to see if there is anything more I can learn from it, and there usually is.